# Limit results in jQuery Autocomplete isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I already browse for a lot of answers in StackOverflow and I think no one have this issue before. It's a little strange, but when I try to limit the results in jQuery Autocomplete, it just doesn't work.

I don't know what I can exactly paste here, so I will paste a little piece of my code and you tell me what's missing.

```
$("input[type=search]").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function (request, response) {
        populate(request.term, response);

        result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term)

        response(result.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I go to my search, this just doesn't work! I still see a lot (and lot, and lot, and lot) of results.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that works for me is to reference things this way.

```
<script>

$(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
$(this).autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
        source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete"),
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                alert(ui.item.id);
            }
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Then using a standard javascript data reference to the location of the autocomplete server side script

```
<input type="text" data-autocomplete="/Home/QuickSearch" />
```

This allows more than one quick search and also handles changing references to the server side location.

In your own code if you keep the opening line, ensure the input type is set to search

```
<input type="search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be mixing up the source option, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source, with the response option, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Check the docs and see if setting it up like this helps:

```
$("input[type=search]").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function (request, response) {
        // return data you want to search against
    },
    response: function(event, ui) {
        // manipulate result data in ui.content and return
    }
}
```

});